# React async await axios call returning promise state pending and then fulfilled

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

Im calling function inside useEffect hook like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getFirstLevelCategoryData = async (e) => {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
            },
        };
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/category/firstlevel', config);
        return data;
    };
    console.log(getFirstLevelCategoryData());
});
```

> Promise { : "pending" }
> ​
> : "fulfilled"
> ​
> : Array(29) [ "Audio", "Automobiles", "Baby & Kids Fashion", … ]

I am using similar code in other place also which is working fine but this one keep giving pending state. Called the API from postman, working fine. Any ideas? Please help.
​

Im expecting an JSON string, but its in pending state.

**UPDATED**

```js
//Declaration of variable:
const [mainCategory, setMainCategory] = useState([]);

// Function outside of useEffect hook to prevent it calling from over and over again

const getFirstLevelCategoryData = async (e) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
    },
  };
  const { data } = await axios.get("/api/category/firstlevel", config);
  setMainCategory(data);
};
if (mainCategory.length === 0) getFirstLevelCategoryData();

//Using it inside <Typeahead/> element in JSX:

<Typeahead
  id="basic-typeahead-single"
  labelKey="category"
  onChange={(e) => setMainCategory(e.target.value)}
  options={mainCategory}
  placeholder="Choose a state..."
  selected=""
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The REQUEST is working fine the issue is that this line :

```js
console.log(getFirstLevelCategoryData());
```

Is executed before the function returning data, try :

```js
const { data } = await axios.get('/api/category/firstlevel', config);
console.log(data)
);
```

And you will see your `data` outputed after `console.log(getFirstLevelCategoryData());`

So what you have to do is to use `data` directly inside the function there is no need to return it

Comment: Thank you, the trick worked but i still didn't understand why i cannot use that function directly in any form field. I was trying to call inside a <Typeahead options = {getFirstLevelCategoryData} /> attribute. Also i moved it outside of Use-effect since i just wanted to call it once, not to render the option over and over again. See my updated answer, how i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are returning a promise from your function so to get the values in a way you're expecting you need to do something like this:

const result = await getFirstLevelCategoryData()

console.log("result", result)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't `await` (or `.then`) `getFirstLevelCategoryData()`, so it actually returns an unresolved promise.

You could use it like this (.then):

```
const getFirstLevelCategoryData = async (e) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      }
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
      config
    );

      return data
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFirstLevelCategoryData()
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
       })
  }, []);
```

Or like this (await):

```
  const getFirstLevelCategoryData = async (e) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      }
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
      config
    );

    // Log data here
    console.log(data)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFirstLevelCategoryData();
  }, []);
```

Here's also a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-river-11y75n